# Linq to Sql - How to update an object using a repository pattern?

Tags: database, linq-to-sql, repository, optimistic-concurrency

There is tons of information on this, but even after reading for hours and hours I can't seem to get this to work the way I want.

I'm trying to update a User object by passing in a User object and generically comparing changes to a User object I pull out of the database.  I always end up getting the NotSupportedException when using this method:

> An attempt has been made to Attach or
>   Add an entity that is not new, perhaps
>   having been loaded from another
>   DataContext.  This is not supported.

Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
    public void SaveUser(User User)
    {
        using (DataContext dataContext = new DataContext(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database"].ConnectionString))
        {
            // New user
            if (User.UserID == 0)
            {
                dataContext.Users.InsertOnSubmit(User);
            }
            // Existing user
            else
            {
                User dbUser = dataContext.Users.Single(u => u.UserID.Equals(User.UserID));
                Type t = dbUser.GetType();
                foreach (PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties())
                {
                    if (p.CanWrite & p.GetValue(dbUser, null) != p.GetValue(User, null))
                    {
                        p.SetValue(dbUser, p.GetValue(User, null), null);
                    }
                }
                //dataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, dbUser);
            }
            dataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

The commented out line I tried uncommented too, but it was no help.

If I comment out the foreach() loop and add a line like dbUser.UserName = "Cheese"; it will update the User's name in the database fine.  That leads me to believe it is something with how the foreach() loop changing the dbUser object that causes this to fail.

When I debug the dbUser object, it appears to correctly acquire all the changes from the User object that was passed as an argument.

I also did some reading on optimistic concurrency and added a column to the table of data type timestamp, but that didn't seem to have any effect either.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

How can I get this to generically detect what has changed and correctly persist the changes to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is there's a foreign key relation that you are trying to copy over that was not initially loaded (because of lazy-loading) During the copying, it's attempting to load it, but the DataContext has already been disposed.

I've been working on a similar problem. I ended up using AutoMapper to handle copying the properties for me. I have configured AutoMapper to ignore the primary key field as well as any relations. Something like:

```
public void Update(User user)
{
     using (var db = new DataContext(...))
     {
         var userFromDb = db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == user.Id).Single();
         AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(user, userFromDb);
         db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

My automapper configuration is something like

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Create<User, User>().ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
                                      .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeRelation, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

You can find AutoMapper here: http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: This looks good, however I suggest using `SubmitChanges()` as it's own method. That way you can pile up a couple of DB calls before submitting them.

Comment: Yep, I agree completely with SubmitChanges() on it's own method. The above is just quick psuedo-code of the pattern. I'd also make my repository expose generic methods to the service layer. I can expand more on it if @Sgraffite would like.

Comment: Well that did the trick, thanks!  I watched the video on their site first and then played around with it some.  I ended up making an automapper configuration method in my global.asax.  I guess you have to list every single table that references the user table when adding the .Ignore() because one single relationship not ignored  to that user will cause it to blow up.  I would like for you to expand on the repository exposing generic methods also as this is my first time using the repository pattern.

Comment: Now I have to remember to update the AutoMapper configuration when I add more foreign keys :(

Comment: Yep, that's the way to do it. AutoMapper also has a method Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); that will check your mappings and throw an assertion if a property is not configured. (i.e. mapping User to UserViewModel, and you are missing some properties on UserViewModel)

Comment: I found the original blog post that describes the repository pattern I'm using: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-irepository-pattern-with-linq-to.html

Answer (score 0):

I keep my repo pretty lean, it's only job is to interact with the database.  I build a Service layer on top of the repo that does a little more work

```
public class EventRepository : IEventRepository
{

    private DBDataContext dc;
    public EventRepository()
    {
        dc = new DBDataContext();
    }

    public void Create(Event @event)
    {
        dc.Events.InsertOnSubmit(@event);
    }

    public System.Linq.IQueryable<Event> Read()
    {
        object events = (from e in dc.Eventse);
        return events.AsQueryable;
    }

    public void SubmitChanges()
    {
        dc.SubmitChanges();
    }

}
```

Then the corresponding call from the service layer looks like this

```
public void AddEvent(Event @event)
{
    _EventRepository.Create(@event);
}

public void SubmitChanges()
{
    _EventRepository.SubmitChanges();
}
```

And I call it from my controller.

```
// AutoMapper will allow us to map the ViewModel with the DomainModel
Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.ViewModels.EventsAddViewModel, Domain.Event>();
object @event = Mapper.Map<Domain.ViewModels.EventsAddViewModel, Domain.Event>(eventToAdd);

// Add the event to the database
EventService.AddEvent(@event);
EventService.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Note this particular example doesn't necessitate a Repository layer AND a Service layer, however in much of my other code I need both.

Comment: also, I don't know if the @ symbol on @events is right, it's just what the converter did when I had `[event]` in VB.

Comment: What is the purpose of creating this "repository" when all it does is wrap methods that are *already* available in the data context?  IMO, the data context is more than sufficient to serve as your actual "repository".

Comment: The purpose is that the REPOSITORY talks to the ORM. Then if I every change the ORM, all I have to do is convert the REPOSITORY over, and my SERVICE never knows the difference. I'm using LINQ to SQL right now, but am considering migrating to ENTITY FRAMEWORK. I'd hate to have to switch up my service layer (has 5x the code) instead of just the repository layer.

Comment: I also put caching in the repository layer. It avoids having to duplicate the caching calls on all my service methods. My service doesn't need to know if data came from a cache or from the database.

Comment: Yes, I agree, Caching is critical, though I put mine in the Service layer. That way I can cache bite size chunks... tomAYtoes, TomAHtoes.